# 日本語に違和感: バナー設定画面全般

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

URL例: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/30/ento/flair

> ご自分のウェブサイトに掲載して、ユーザー プロフィールを**披露**できる**有益**なバナー<sup>**tm**</sup> です。
>
> テーマ: **ホットドッグ売店**
>
> 複数の Stack Exchange サイトに参加しているユーザーは、それぞれのプロフィールを**統合**して**披露**することもできます:
>
> **使用方法は?**
>
> 以下の HTML **スニペット**をコピーして、スタック・オーバーフローMeta バナーを**披露**したい場所に貼り付けるだけです:
>
> … そして、**統合**した Stack Exchange バナー**には**:

**太字**：違和感のある箇所

ホットドッグ売店: hotdog のままでよいと思う

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これは何？

バナーをウェブサイトやブログに設置することで、スタック・オーバーフローのプロフィールを訪問者に披露できます。

テーマ: hotdog

複数の Stack Exchange コミュニティに参加している場合、各プロフィールをまとめて表示することもできます:

使い方は？

スタック・オーバーフローMeta のバナーを設置したい場所に、以下の HTML コードをコピーして貼り付けるだけです:

Stack Exchange ネットワークバナーはこちら:

Comment: [Transifexに提案として反映しました](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40288579?comment=%2Fq%2F289%2F8000)。ホットドッグ売店は原文が`hot dog stand`だったので、原文ママにしてます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらのメタ投稿は解決済みにします